# Echo is not printing certain variables

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having some problem with my code not printing certain variables even if the variables has a string in it.

```
$ dmisysname=$(sed -ne 148p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ dmibrdname=$(sed -ne 157p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ echo $dmisysname $dmibrdname
```

This should give me whatever inside $dmisysname and $dmibrdname, but the output displays this:

> X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+

To make sure that the 2 variables have a string in it, I echo each variable individually.

```
$ echo $dmisysname
```

> PIO-647R-6RLN4F+-ST031

```
$ echo $dmibrdname
```

> X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+

Am I doing something wrong that has to do something with the print buffer or is there a bigger problem that I don't see?

Comment: $ echo "$(sed -ne 148p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')"
PIO-647R-6RLN4F+-ST031
$ echo "$(sed -ne 157p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')"
X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+

Comment: Are you sure there's no other hidden characters or something? I had no trouble with the `echo $dmisysname $dmibrdname`. You could try, `echo "$dmisysname" "$dmibrdname"` perhaps and see if the result is different.

Comment: no, still the same
$ echo "$dmisysname" "$dmibrdname"
 X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  What do lines 148 and 157 of this file look like?

Comment: Maybe try `echo $dmisysname | od -c` and see if you spot any non-visible characters.

Comment: @lurker `$ echo $dmisysname | od -c
0000000   P   I   O   -   6   4   7   R   -   6   R   L   N   4   F   +
0000020   -   S   T   0   3   1  \r  \n
0000030`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `$ echo "$(sed -ne 148p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt)"      Product = PIO-647R-6RLN4F+-ST031`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf this is from a new terminal, I ran `set -u` and nothing pops up

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf still the same output, I'm missing `$dmisysname`

Comment: it is because of `\r` in your variable

Comment: @Ashkan ah, it is because of `\r`, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file was created under windows, and as such uses CRLF line terminations.  This causes the output from [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) under [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) to be confused, relative to what is expected, as per [@Lurker's useful explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23252645/2113226).

Use the `dos2unix` utility to fix your file:

```
$ dmisysname=$(sed -ne 148p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ dmibrdname=$(sed -ne 157p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ echo $dmisysname $dmibrdname
 X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+
$ dos2unix 3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txtdos2unix: converting file 3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt to Unix format ...
$ dmisysname=$(sed -ne 148p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ dmibrdname=$(sed -ne 157p ./3A47083/S09850724414683/002590F3851A.txt | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/ //')
$ echo $dmisysname $dmibrdname
PIO-647R-6RLN4F+-ST031 X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+
$
```

I recreated a workable version of your file under Linux, then used `unix2dos` to format it as per windows.  Then I am able to recreate your problem.  Reverting it back using `dos2unix` fixes it.

Comment: @lurker True.  Edited with a reference to your useful explanation.

Comment: Good idea on the `dos2unix`. And nice avatar. (+1) :)

Answer (score 2):

Each of your variables ends in a carriage return (`\r`). So what happens is both are echoed, but the second one overwrites the first.

I'll illustrate with the -e option:

```
$ echo -e "FOO\rBAR\r"
BAR
```

But both are being echoed. It's just that `BAR` is overwriting `FOO`:

```
$ echo -e "FOO\rBAR\r" | od -c
0000000   F   O   O  \r   B   A   R  \r  \n
0000011
```